# Type checker in trouble over @specialized

Tags: scala

The trait below compiles fine without the `@specialized` annotations, or without the `map` method. Otherwise, it will fail with a compilation error, which doesn't make a lot of sense (at least to me):

```
[error] (compile:compile) scala.tools.nsc.symtab.Types$TypeError: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : U(in method foreach)(in method foreach)
[error]  required: U(in method foreach)(in method foreach)
```

This is the trait that I'm talking about:

```
trait Tuple2Traversable[@specialized(Int, Byte) +A, @specialized(Int, Byte) +B] {

  def foreach[T](fn: (A, B) => T)

  def map[T](fn: (A, B) => T): Traversable[T] = new Traversable[T] {
    def foreach[U](f: T => U) {
      def composed(a: A, b: B) = f(fn(a, b))
      Tuple2Traversable.this.foreach(composed)
    }
  }

  def flatMap[T](fn: (A, B) => Traversable[T]): Traversable[T] = new Traversable[T] {
    def foreach[U](f: (T) => U) {
      def composed(a: A, b: B) = fn(a, b).foreach(f)
      Tuple2Traversable.this.foreach(composed)
    }
  }

  def filter(included: (A, B) => Boolean): Tuple2Traversable[A, B] = new Tuple2Traversable[A, B] {
    def foreach[T](fn: (A, B) => T) {
      def composed(a: A, b: B) = if (included(a, b)) fn(a, b)
      Tuple2Traversable.this.foreach(composed)
    }
  }

  def foldLeft[T](z: T)(fn: (T, A, B) => T): T = {
    var current = z
    def op(a: A, b: B) {
      current = fn(current, a, b)
    }
    foreach(op)
    current
  }

  def asTraversable = new Traversable[(A, B)] {
    def foreach[U](f: ((A, B)) => U) {
      def tupled(a: A, b: B) = f((a, b))
      Tuple2Traversable.this.foreach(tupled)
    }
  }

}
```

I've been staring at this for a while now. Any suggestions on how to solve this would be highly appreciated.

Perhaps I should add that the purpose of this class is to have a Traversable of tuples, without forcing those tuples to ever be created. A `Traversable[(A,B)]` would accept a  `Tuple2[A,B] => T` as the parameter of `foreach`. I want my 'traversable' to accept a function `(A, B) => T`. (Like `def fn(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b`.)

Comment: I do not have an answer, but a side note: You can use a self reference `trait Tuple2Traversable ... { self => ... }` in order to allow a replacement from `Tuple2Traversable.this.foreach` to `self.foreach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like some internal compiler bug. I get the same error in scala 2.9.2, but it compiles fine in scala 2.10-RC2

Comment: I'm on 2.9.2 as well, but I don't want to limit my code to 2.10 only just because of this issue. The weird thing is that none of the other methods have problems with the @specialized annotation.